# Liquibase update Failed due to Property 'forIndexName' not found on object type liquibase.change.core.AddUniqueConstraintChange

Tags: java, database, oracle, liquibase

I am running a Liquibase migration on my project. But it gives the below error.

```
Liquibase update Failed: Invalid Migration File: java.lang.RuntimeException: Property 'forIndexName' not found on object type liquibase.change.core.AddUniqueConstraintChange
```

I tried using liquibase versions 4.3.2 and 4.11.0. Both gave the same error.

I am using Oracle as the database.

Removing this property from the changelog file didn't work because then it gives the same error for another property in the changelog file.

Please give a solution for this.